# Why did my 2 buttons stop working?

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

Why did my 2 image buttons stop working after I added code for the email intent. I have been fiddling with the `Public Void onCreate bundle` and when I move that section of code below, it works again. Have I nested them incorrectly? Could someone please correct it?

My OnClickListener is basically not working as the button does nothing when clicked.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class contactActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private WebView webView;
    private WebView webView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        Button mail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Sendbutton);
        mail.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.Sendbutton:
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                String[] recipients = new String[]{"email add", "",};
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample mail");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a sample mail..");
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail client :"));
                finish();
                break;
        }

        ImageButton ViewFacebookFeed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ViewFacebookFeed);
        ImageButton ViewTwitterFeed = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.ViewTwitterFeed);

        //Add a listener to ImageButton1
        ViewFacebookFeed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openBrowser1();
            }           
        });                             
        ViewTwitterFeed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openBrowser2();
            }           
        });
    }
    private void openBrowser1() 
    {       
        //this intent is used to open other activity which contains another webView
        Intent intent = new Intent(contactActivity.this,fbtwitterfeedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    private void openBrowser2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(contactActivity.this,twitterfeedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the "onClickListeners are not working"?

Comment: Is your OnClickListener being called?  Can you put a log statement in there to verify that?

Comment: @CaseyB Why add code?  Why not just a breakpoint?

Comment: You don't set the click listeners on ViewFacebookFeed and ViewTwitterFeed until your send button is clicked for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you had it implemented, you only registered your button clicks after you clicked the "send" button. You call finish() in the send onClick so the listeners would never get registered. Register your listeners in onCreate and then listen for the clicks on the specific view ID in your onClick method. I've fixed your code so that you register the click listeners at the proper time and your onClick method handles all clicks from all buttons

```
public class contactActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private WebView webView;
    private WebView webView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        Button mail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Sendbutton);
        mail.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageButton viewFacebookFeed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ViewFacebookFeed);
        viewFacebookFeed.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButton viewTwitterFeed = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.ViewTwitterFeed);
        viewTwitterFeed.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.Sendbutton:
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                String[] recipients = new String[]{"email add", "",};
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample mail");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a sample mail..");
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail client :"));
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.ViewFacebookFeed:
                openBrowser1();
                break;
            case R.id.ViewTwitterFeed:
                openBrowser2();
                break;

        }
    }
    private void openBrowser1() 
    {       
        //this intent is used to open other activity which contains another webView
        Intent intent = new Intent(contactActivity.this,fbtwitterfeedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    private void openBrowser2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(contactActivity.this,twitterfeedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much code works perfectly. do you know how to add input field and checkboxes to send with the email

Comment: You'd need to add CheckBox and EditText elements to your xml layout file and then reference them in code.

Comment: i have them in my XML but im able to code them in so that they come up in the email. My send `details button` works as it bring up popup for email chooser, but in the message i cannot get the name phone date to come. the Id of my input feilds are R.id.Nameinput, R.id.Phoneinput, R.id.dateinput .....Checkboxes are R.id.Checkbox1 .Checkbox2 .Checkbox3  . please advise

Comment: You can do something like String name = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.Nameinput)).getText().toString();

Comment: And then pass that into your email intent emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a sample mail.. With a " + name);

Comment: You obviously can modify this to however you need to use the values.I don't know what you want with the checkboxes. If you need additional help you can search around on the internet or open up a new question.

Comment: could you kindly add that in your answer in code? if not, i think i shall open up a new question as im baffled

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not implement an interface from the activity, but from the object directly.
I have rewritted your code, it is better like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class contactActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private WebView webView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        Button mail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sendbutton);
        ImageButton ViewFacebookFeed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ViewFacebookFeed);
        ImageButton ViewTwitterFeed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ViewTwitterFeed);
        // Add a listener to ImageButton1
        ViewFacebookFeed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openBrowser1();
            }
        });
        ViewTwitterFeed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openBrowser2();
            }
        });
        mail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                String[] recipients = new String[] { "email add", "", };
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample mail");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a sample mail..");
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail client :"));
                finish();
            }

        });
    }

    private void openBrowser1() {
        // this intent is used to open other activity which contains another
        // webView
        Intent intent = new Intent(contactActivity.this, fbtwitterfeedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void openBrowser2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(contactActivity.this, twitterfeedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }

}
```